# Is there any other container similar to a set with the lookup performance of a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, set, duplicates

Basically, I have many vectors which store binary data. I want to de-duplicate them. So the first thing that came to my mind is a `set`. However the lookup performance of `set` doesn't match that of a vector. Is there any other container which can de-duplicate data and perform faster?
I need fast lookup because, the binary data is fetched from a server, de-duplicated and sent to the client and this is a conitnuous process.

Comment: By lookup you mean `find` operation or random access? If you are referring to `find` then `set` is faster than `vector`.

Comment: Since I'm dealing with binary data, I don't know what to `find`. So I am looking at random access. The bottleneck here is the `insert` operation on a set. Its really slow

Comment: Can the data be sorted or does it need to be in inserted order?

Comment: The data shouldn't be sorted. I also checked unordered_set. I have a `struct newtype`. Somehow, I cannot create an instance of unordered_set of the particular type `newtype`.

Comment: In the post you say the bottleneck is lookup. Which is it? Insertion or "lookup"? And if you don't know what to find, how are you going to look it up? Between your misuse of terminology and lack of code, it's impossible to tell what you're actually asking.

Comment: @kfsone Both the insertion and lookup are creating the bottlenecks here. Set is an unsuitable container here. Basically I want to de-duplicate the data. And have something like FIFO property. I know set is not at all suitable in this case

Comment: If your insert is slow, chances are you are inserting something that takes a (relatively) long time to copy. Why not simply insert a pointer, and avoid the copy altogether? Also, for unordered_set you need to provide an appropriate hash function. Plenty of examples around for how to do that.

Comment: Why the downvote @kfsone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many options, but all depends upon your data. Going for a `*set` data structure sounds like the default option, but you have to *Measure* with some realistic set of data.

Let me jot down some brief points on the available containers that you can check.

- Set

  ```
  Elements are sorted.
  Don't have to worry about removing of duplicate entries.
  Its a node based container, so no performance benefits from cache locality.
  Try to go for boost::flat_set
  ```
- Unordered_Set

  ```
  No ordering of elements, So not sorted by default.
  Hash based container, so would seem like it would provide better performance. 
  Hashing of large keys will result in poor performance, 
  So, will have to resort to an augmented data structure which maps the actual data key to some integer value based on partial hashing of the key or something.
  But, that depends upon hashing performance. Again, *Measure* (can't stress enough)
  ```
- Vector

  ```
  Upto a certain number of elements, this would certainly beat std::set for performance.
  Upto you to find that range.
  std::sort followed by std::unique will give you deduplicated range of data.
  Should consider boost::flat_set before implementing a set using vector on your own.
  ```
- boost::flat_set

  ```
  Already discussed as above.
  ```

So to summarize, you have to do your performance measurement tests on your data set.